# How to achieve side by side output in Bash?

Tags: bash

I have a script, let's say it's this (obviously, my real one is much more complicated):

```
echo A
echo a
echo B
echo b
echo C
echo c
echo D
echo d
```

Is there an easy way to have the lines side by side?

```
A    a
B    b
C    c
D    d
```

Or would it be better if I separate it into 2 files then merge them? How would I go about that?

Comment: Skip bash, use e.g. Python, Curses and Windows -> docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html

Comment: You may use `echo -n` to not output the trailing newline. The rest of the question is a matter of opinion.

Comment: echo -en "hello\n"

Comment: If you're just looking for pretty display to the user then git exposes its logic for printing columns as an executable: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-column

Comment: I'm sure `awk` could be a part of this, depends how your data is stored.

Comment: What's wrong with `echo A a`?? Replace `a` and `A` with the appropriate text producing commands, like `echo $(echo A) $(echo a)` or whatever. For more format control use bash's `printf`: `printf "Two outputs: %s and %s\n" "A" "a"`.

Comment: @Hannu python isn't necessary for this simple task

Comment: @qwr and why would you rule out one of the tools?  <;-D

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A portable tool for this is `paste`:

```
(
    echo A
    echo a
    echo B
    echo b
    echo C
    echo c
    echo D
    echo d
) | paste - -
```

From the [specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html):

> The default operation of `paste` shall concatenate the corresponding lines of the input files. The <newline> of every line except the line from the last input file shall be replaced with a <tab>.
>
> […]
>
> If `-` is specified for one or more of the files, the standard input shall be used; the standard input shall be read one line at a time, circularly, for each instance of `-`.

Lines of varying length may generate output that is not perfectly aligned. To see an example, run:

```
(
    echo A line longer than others
    echo a
    echo B
    echo b
) | paste - -
```

You can fix this by piping to `column`:

```
(
    echo A line longer than others
    echo a
    echo B
    echo b
) | paste - - | column -t -s $'\t'
```

Notes:

- `$'\t'` generates a tab character [in some shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/371827/108618), portably you can do it with `"$(printf '\t')"`.
- `column` itself is not portable though.
- `column` needs to know its whole input before it prints any output, so it's not a good tool to process something you need to see immediately; and it's the wrong tool to process data that may never end (e.g. from a potentially endless loop).

Comment: In the situation where you know the maximum length of the first column, and so want things both aligned and streamed, you can set your terminal's tabstops to be just larger than the maximum length of the first column using `tabs`, or tweak the output text itself with `expand`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `fmt` to format the output:

```bash
(
    echo A
    echo a
    echo B
    echo b
    echo C
    echo c
    echo D
    echo d
) | fmt -w 4
```

Comment: What if the lines are longer? What if the lines are of varying length? What if their lengths are not known in advance?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I guess the problem as specified is not well defined

Answer (score 7):

One approach is to avoid printing the newline after all but the last field on each line.  (Especially if you have lines with different numbers of fields.)

Some platforms can do this in the `echo` command (e.g. by adding an option flag, or a special sequence in the string), but I think the simplest portable way is to use the [`printf`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) command instead.  For example:

```
printf "A    "
echo a
printf "B    "
echo b
printf "C    "
echo c
printf "D    "
echo d
```

You could of course use a tab or other separator instead of 4 spaces.

In more complex cases (e.g. if the text could include characters such as `%`), then you'll need to use an explicit format string, e.g. `printf "%s    " "A"`.

That would also allow you to align variable-length fields if you wanted.  For example:

```
printf "%-5s" A
echo a
printf "%-5s" BB
echo b
printf "%-5s" CCC
echo c
printf "%-5s" DDDD
echo d
```

gives the output:

```
A    a
BB   b
CCC  c
DDDD d
```

(You can use right justification by removing the `-`; `printf` has many other formatting options too.)

Comment: While you're at it, why not replace all instances of `echo` with `printf`?

Comment: @spuck That would work too, of course!  And arguably be better.  (Consistency is important.)  But I thought this answer would be clearer if it kept close to the code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume here that your sequence of echo commands is just an illustration that produces lines of text which in real life are coming from, say, an application; so that simply saying `echo -n` every other time, or replacing `echo` with `printf` would not work.

Then there is this bare-bones solution with a function `produce_output()` as a stand-in for your output-producing program:

```
$ produce_output() { echo A; echo a; echo B; echo b; echo C; echo c; echo D; echo d; }
$ produce_output | while read s1; do read s2; echo "$s1" "$s2"; done
A a
B b
C c
D d
```

Of course you can use the [`printf` command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/printf.1.html) instead of `echo`  for more output format control.